Function not defined despite static js script loaded by express
I'm trying to use a function to change the value inside a text entry when a button is clicked by using "onclick"
<button type="button" id="test" onclick="generate(12)">generate new pass</button>

I know this function works because if I add the function with a script tag, it works as attended.
However, It does not work if I put it in a static js file and I'm getting a "generate is not defined"
the js file is being loaded by the browser because I checked the network tab so that shouldn't be an issue

The most common cause of this is using type="module" when loading the .js file.

Can you elaborate on how you are including the JavaScript code on the page, and how specifically you have confirmed that it is being included?

Or else.. probably you should use in the script tag the defer attribute to load the js file after the body render. Other than that, use event listeners

@David inspect mode and going to the network tab in firefox shows 304 status for the static.js file that I have

@Barmar I am using type="module" in my project, is there a workaround or should I just remove it and convert all of my imports?

In the module assign the function to window.generate.

@Barmar like
window.generate = {code in here}?
generate is still not defined

See the linked question for many solutions.

sigh, none of those solutions work for me
